# Return a value if no record ( MYSQL + PHP )

Tags: php, mysql, null, record, zero

Here's my problem i want to get data from database and i show them in a table that table contain date and another values all based on that date so my problem is when i get the data if a date doesnt have a value in certain title it didn't return as 0 ( Zero ) and that affect my table and it's sorting , here is my query

```
        <?php
            $confirmquery= " SELECT ddate , count(status) as stat from booking_vip where status = 'CONFIRM' AND ddate >= '$date_1' AND ddate <= '$date_2'  GROUP BY ddate";
            $confirmrun=mysql_query($confirmquery);
            while($confirmrow=mysql_fetch_array($confirmrun)){
                        ?>
            <td>
                <?php
                echo $confirmrow['stat'];
                 ?>
            </td>
            <?php   } ?>
```

the query work fine but when there is no record for certain date it didn't return anything so it ruin my table by make a record be in a wrong date ..

so please help me , i searched a lot and tried many functions like ifnull and isnull and COALESCE all of them didn't work for me , is there is any php solutio ,

what i get as example

```
Date        status
2016-03-14  CONFIRM
2016-03-17  CONFIRM
```

What i want is :

```
Date        Total
2016-03-14  CONFIRM
2016-03-15  0
2016-03-16  0
2016-03-17  CONFIRM
```

i want to be zero's in the missing dates that doesnt have any value , i see the question around the community but didn't get any php solution or easy mysql solution .

appreciate your help .

Answer (score 1):

**Note : Stop using `Mysql` its deprecated**

There are multiple way to do that

```
$confirmquery = " SELECT ddate , count(status) as stat from booking_vip where status = 'CONFIRM' AND ddate >= '$date_1' AND ddate <= '$date_2'  GROUP BY ddate";
$confirmrun = mysql_query($confirmquery);
$numRow = mysql_num_rows($confirmrun);
if($numRow > 0){
    //your code
}else{
    echo 0;
}
```

Or

```
   $count = count($confirmrun);
   if($count > 0){
        //your code
    }else{
        echo 0;
    }
```

Comment: thanks urfusion for your help really appreciate it but my problem that even when i do that it didn't work like i want , what i want is when else condition i want it to return 0 but it didn't work though , if you can help i'll appreciate it .

Comment: @HazemMofeed : just `echo 0;` instead of `echo "no record";` Or if you are returning then `return false;`

Comment: thanks bro for your fast comment , but it's just not easy like that i tried to echo to display it but i think the problem in the query that it didn't return any zero so the if condition will never get to else condition , my problem is that i need to make the query return zero when that date doesn't contain a value , wish i clarify it , thanks bro

Comment: Try to pass static `date` that is not in you DB table. For example `$date_2 = '2017-10-14 00:00:00'`. I think it should work now.

Comment: still didn't work :(

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: no there is no error i will give you a screenshot of the problem

Comment: is will be better if you attach screenshot of your table

Comment: https://imgur.com/mhnSYFo this is the screenshot the problem is there is two values beside each other that 2  and 1 the problem is that the 1 is belong to the date 2017-10-14 and the 2 belongs to 2017-10-12 as it is so the date between must be 0 i can't get to make it happen .. wish you get me . thanks alot

Comment: Show your table with data.

Comment: please look at my question again i edited it and i clarify it more . thanks man